# Why are you moderators so strict?

Tags: discussion

You closed this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/243309/how-to-find-original-source-code-of-javascript-implementation-code

What is wrong with that question?

Obviously one user's opinion does not matter so much. People only matter at the aggregate level, not singly. But by being this strict, you guys really just push people away from your website. Maybe you do not care. You seem to be making OK money from the site from those (excuse me) stupid ads on the right column. I was really into that question and at one point it had 6 upvotes (until you guys started down-voting it as a result of this question), Why does this website have to be so censored?

Comment: @RPM - Chris Zumbrunn has an OpenMocha thing going, maybe contact him and see if he has any links.

Comment: Can definitely see your point.  Community moderation only works if you don't have a biased community.

Comment: "Stupid" ads? The SE sites have some of the most low-key ads on the internet. By keeping the question level high, it helps keep the site at a certain level. If you think that's "censorship", you need a better dictionary.

Answer (score 9):

Have you read the close reason?

> "Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Or the ["what not to ask" section of the listing of what's on-topic here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

> where to find a software library, tool or other resource

To address your specific points, question quality is extremely important to Stack Exchange. To attract experts in a particular subject area, the questions need to be interesting and relevant. We have a very specific [scope](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), relatively strict [guidelines for what makes a good question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and [rules for post quality and content](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). These rules are what make Stack Exchange successful, draw in experts, and provide high quality answers for people who are searching for them (Google loves Stack Exchange sites - many are often on the first page or two of Google if there's a related question).

Sometimes, the community is wrong. Up votes don't mean that a question should remain open. If it doesn't belong, it should be closed. If possible, it should be cleaned up to make it appropriate for the site. If not, then it may eventually be deleted so that the site eventually becomes a set of high quality questions with high quality answers that solve people's problems.

Comment: @RPM - You asked a dumb question that is clearly spelled out as off topic, and you got your hand slapped. Whining about it on meta won't change anything.

Comment: @RPM have you read the FAQ for this site?

Answer (score 7):

In your question on main, you asked:

> I was hoping to find the original implementation, or the interpreter for the scripting language. Is this goal capable of being reached, or in other words, can I find it on the internet somewhere?

This basically translates into two separate questions:

1. Where can I find the original implementation.
2. Can I find the original implementation on the internet.

The first is a request for an off-site resource.  Thomas' answer explains why that's off-topic for the site.

The second simply isn't answerable by the community except in answering the first question.  The negative ("No, it can't be found") can't be conclusively proven.